# Como crear vistas en Mysql con @

Tags: mysql

Tengo una consulta de varias tablas el cual llamare tabla_construida, que me muestra lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo que busco es crear una vista que me acumule lo que se tiene un registro antes, dependiendo de que sea de la misma region y del mismo trabajo. si hago una consulta el query seria el siguiente:

```
SELECT region
  , semana
 , tipo_trabajo
 , trab_ejecutados
 , @acumulado_eje := if( (region,tipo_trabajo)=(@region,@trabajo)
                   , @acumulado_eje
                   , ifnull( concat( @region := region
                                   , @trabajo := tipo_trabajo
                                   , null
                                   )
                           , 0
                           )
                   ) 
               + trab_ejecutados acumulado1    
 FROM tabla_construida t
  JOIN ( SELECT @acumulado_eje := 0
            , @region  := null
            , @trabajo := null
     ) vars
```

lo cual me muestra de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero cuando quiero crear una vista con este codigo, me sale el siguiente error

```
 #1351 - View's SELECT contains a variable or parameter
```

habra alguna manera de crear una vista que acepte los @